# MalformedJsonEception erron while deserializing string

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a JSON string that i want to de-serialize into a class that i'e created but i always get:

> JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON

The JSON string which i have to de-serialize is:

```
[{"UserId":"admin","Description":"Administrator","PIN":"00001"}]
```

so i've created a User class like this one:

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("UserId")
private String userId;
@SerializedName("Description")
private String description;
@SerializedName("PIN")
private String pin;

public User(){
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    userId = userId;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    description = description;
}

public String getPIN() {
    return pin;
}

public void setPIN(String PIN) {
    this.pin = PIN;
}
```

}

In an activity I call:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User[] users = gson.fromJson(server, User[].class); //server is the json string to de-serialize
```

I've tried to do this stuff using online tools to create the User's class structure from the JSON string or defining private strings of the class with case sensitive name as in the string, but always got that exception.

I've even tried with a JsonReader but i had an error while passing it as argument of gson.fromGson()

Comment: Have you printed then `server` string to see what is there?

Comment: If i print that string i have the JSON string that i've posted, it's the first thing that i've done

Comment: I would check if `User[] users = gson.fromJson("[{\"UserId\":\"admin\",\"Description\":\"Administrator\",\"PIN\":\"00001\"}]", User[].class);` works. If not the problem is in the parse else the issue is in the `server` string.

Comment: i've tried to de-serialize that string and it works, i will check the http request which give me the json string